# How do web-software related questions differ in superuser from questions in webapps of stackexhange?

Tags: support, allowed-topics, websites

I guess the web related software questions can be asked in either of the websites - superuser or webapps? Am I correct?

Answer (score 6):

If it's about a problem with the browser, it belongs on Super User.

If you have an issue with using a website or web app, it belongs on Web Apps.

However, if you have a question about browser plugins that interact with specific web apps, I I would encourage anyone to ask these questions on Web Apps, rather than Super User

All website related questions are explicitly off-topic for Super User, as [you can read in our FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq)

Comment: much simpler than mine :)

Answer (score 3):

Refering to the FAQ:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> computer hardware
>   computer software
>   and it is not about …
>
> videogames or consoles
>   websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
>   electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer
>   a shopping or buying recommendation
>   … then you're in the right place to ask your question!

and the FAQ of Web Apps states:

> What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> Web Apps - Stack Exchange is for expert and advanced users of web applications, so if your question generally covers …
>
> Gmail
>   Facebook
>   Twitter
>   Google
>   … or any other website which behaves like an application, then you're in the right place >to ask your question!

With that said, it appears that interpretation allows for questions to be synonymous nature.